# It is possible to add/remove tabs in ViewPager at run time?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreateView");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // setting up the view pager and tab layout
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));

    return rootView;
}
```

My custom pager adapter looks like this:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new GroupTabFragment(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = "";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                title = "Game";    // this is from a template, i have to
                break;             // return title dynamically
            case 1:
                title = "Movie";
                break;
        }
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;                  // the tabs number is a subject of change
    }                              // i don't know it from the begining
}
```

The problem i have is that i have to add or remove a tab when a button is clicked, or something like this.

Each tab will display a classic list of objects.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 ways doing this although `ViewPager` is not suitable for dynamic removing:

1) Pass `ArrayList<Fragment> data` as parameter to `PageAdapter`

Then Adapter will look like this:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<Fragment> data;

public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> data) {
    super(fm);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String title = "";
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            title = "Game";    // this is from a template, i have to
            break;             // return title dynamically
        case 1:
            title = "Movie";
            break;
    }
    return title;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();                  // the tabs number is a subject of change
}                              // i don't know it from the begining
```

}

to remove item you do in Activity\Fragment:

```
data.remove(fragmentId);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

2) Recreate adapter every time you want to delete item. So you basically create new adapter with new data.

```
data.remove(fragmentId);
PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), data);
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to add another tabs at some button click?

Comment: jup. `data.add(new YourFragment());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);` you can setup your tabs manually:

```
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Movie"));
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Game"));
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Audio"));
mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
```

Removing is also easy: `removeTabAt(int position)` or `removeTab(Tab tab)`

Comment: Yes, this works. But when i call it from another function crashs with java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.newTab()' on a null object reference

Comment: Is there any possibility to add another tabs at some button click?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have found some better solution to remove all the views / fragments from the current context.

Here I have used TabLayout and ViewPage within Fragment.
So we need to clear tabs from TabLayout, views from ViewPage and fragments from FragmentManager.

```
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = null;
    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager pager) {
        super(manager);
        this.fragmentManager= manager;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
        this.viewPager= pager;
    }

    public void removeAll() {
        tabLayout.removeAllTabs();
        viewPager.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        viewPager.removeAllViews();
        viewPager.setAdapter(null);

        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        if (manager.getFragments() != null) {
            manager.getFragments().clear();
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterPage);
        viewPager.invalidate();
        viewPager.requestLayout();

        mFragmentList.clear();
        mFragmentTitleList.clear();
    }
```